# Determinism in C++ standard library

Tags: c++, stl, deterministic

`std::sort` is not guaranteed to be stable.

Is it guaranteed to be deterministic though?

For example, will this code always print `1`?

```
struct S
{
    int a, b;
};

bool cmp(const S& lhs, const S& rhs)
{
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> seq1 = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}};
    std::vector<S> seq2 = seq1;
    std::sort(seq1.begin(), seq1.end(), cmp);
    std::sort(seq2.begin(), seq2.end(), cmp);
    std::cout << (seq1.back().b == seq2.back().b) << '\n';
}
```

Also, is C++ standard library deterministic in general (apart from obviously indeterministic elements, like RNG and clocks)?

Comment: I don't believe the standard guarantees such determinism. To the best of my knowledge, it's silent on the issue, so the implementation is not required to be deterministic.

Comment: In fact, for the core language, it explicitly states the opposite (possibly in a non-normative note; I'm too lazy to look it up) - something to the effect that, in an expression like `f() + g()`, the order of the two function calls is unspecified, and moreover doesn't have to be the same between two evaluations of this expressions.

Comment: There is no such guarantee. Use [`stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) to be safe.

Comment: One possible reason of instability is if thread is used under the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only requirement on a range once it has been sorted with `std::sort` is that the the elements are ordered according to the provided predicate. So if there are multiple valid orderings that are possible, then an implementation is conforming so long as it generates any one of them.

An implementation is allowed to generate different orderings each time `std::sort` is called on the same range. It can also generate a different ordering each time the program is executed.

Here are the [requirements](https://eel.is/c++draft/sort) on `std::sort`. Note that there is no mention of any requirement that the resulting ranges be the same every time, so there is no guarantee that the results will be deterministic.

Comment: Please link source and I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Phastasm I've linked to the standard page. There's no specific wording that says that it's "non-deterministic", but I think that can be inferred from the lack of a guarantee that it is "deterministic".

Comment: As well as the fact that there is stable_sort if more is required.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Stability and determinism are not the same and one could require just determinism like in the code from question.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir That doesn't actually prove that sort is non-deterministic. While it would be rather strange to guarantee determinism *without* stability, that would be possible, as Phastasm points out.

Comment: pdqsort is deterministic but unstable. It simply uses a fixed seed for its randomness. Of course that is one implementation that can define its own guarantees. Rust uses it to implement its standard`sort_unstable`, but that interface also does not guarantee determinism.